# Theorem 12.4 in "A Probabilistic Theory of Pattern Recognition"

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality

I'm studying the book [A Probabilistic Theory of Pattern Recognition](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-0711-5). I'm trying to understand every detail in the proofs and got stuck in an inequality presented in the STEP 1 of the proof of Theorem 12.4.

To give as much detail as possible, I present below the theorem and the proof of the STEP 1 (as in the book).

---

Theorem 12.4. (GLIVENKO-CANTELLI THEOREM). Let $Z_1, \ldots, Z_n$ be i.i.d. real-valued random variables with distribution function $F(z)=\mathbf{P}\left\{Z_1 \leq z\right\}$. Denote the standard empirical distribution function by
$$
F_n(z)=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n I_{\left\{Z_i \leq z\right\}} .
$$
Then
$$
\mathbf{P}\left\{\sup _{z \in \mathcal{R}}\left|F(z)-F_n(z)\right|>\epsilon\right\} \leq 8(n+1) e^{-n \epsilon^2 / 32},
$$
and, in particular, by the Borel-Cantelli lemma,
$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup _{z \in \mathcal{R}}\left|F(z)-F_n(z)\right|=0 \text { with probability one. }
$$

---

PROOF. The proof presented here is not the simplest possible, but it contains the main ideas leading to a powerful generalization. Introduce the notation $\nu(A)=$ $\mathbf{P}\left\{Z_1 \in A\right\}$ and $\nu_n(A)=(1 / n) \sum_{j=1}^n I_{\left\{Z_j \in A\right\}}$ for all measurable sets $A \subset \mathcal{R}$. Let $\mathcal{A}$ denote the class of sets of form $(-\infty, z]$ for $z \in \mathcal{R}$. With these notations,
$$
\sup _{z \in \mathcal{R}}\left|F(z)-F_n(z)\right|=\sup _{A \in \mathcal{A}}\left|\nu_n(A)-\nu(A)\right| .
$$
We prove the theorem in several steps, following symmetrization ideas of Dudley (1978), and Pollard (1984). We assume that $n \epsilon^2 \geq 2$, since otherwise the bound is trivial. In the first step we introduce a symmetrization.

STEP 1. FIRST SYMMETRIZATION BY A GHOST SAMPLE. Define the random variables $Z_1^{\prime}, \ldots, Z_n^{\prime} \in \mathcal{R}$ such that $Z_1, \ldots, Z_n, Z_1^{\prime}, \ldots, Z_n^{\prime}$ are all independent and identically distributed. Denote by $\nu_n^{\prime}$ the empirical measure corresponding to the new sample:
$$
\nu_n^{\prime}(A)=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n I_{\left\{Z_i^{\prime} \in A\right\}} .
$$
Then for $n \epsilon^2 \geq 2$ we have
$$
\mathbf{P}\left\{\sup _{A \in \mathcal{A}}\left|\nu_n(A)-\nu(A)\right|>\epsilon\right\} \leq 2 \mathbf{P}\left\{\sup _{A \in \mathcal{A}}\left|\nu_n(A)-\nu_n^{\prime}(A)\right|>\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right\} .
$$

To see this, let $A^* \in \mathcal{A}$ be a set for which $\left|\nu_n\left(A^*\right)-\nu\left(A^*\right)\right|>\epsilon$ if such a set exists, and let $A^*$ be a fixed set in $\mathcal{A}$ otherwise. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{P} & \left\{\sup _{A \in \mathcal{A}}\left|\nu_n(A)-\nu_n^{\prime}(A)\right|>\epsilon / 2\right\} \\
& \geq \mathbf{P}\left\{\left|\nu_n\left(A^*\right)-\nu_n^{\prime}\left(A^*\right)\right|>\epsilon / 2\right\} \\
& \geq \mathbf{P}\left\{\left|\nu_n\left(A^*\right)-\nu\left(A^*\right)\right|>\epsilon,\left|\nu_n^{\prime}\left(A^*\right)-\nu\left(A^*\right)\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right\} \\
& =\mathbf{E}\left\{I_{\left\{\left|\nu_n\left(A^*\right)-\nu\left(A^*\right)\right|>\epsilon\right\}} \mathbf{P}\left\{\left|\nu_n^{\prime}\left(A^*\right)-\nu\left(A^*\right)\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{2} \mid Z_1, \ldots, Z_n\right\}\right\} .
\end{aligned}
$$
The conditional probability inside may be bounded by Chebyshev's inequality as follows:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{P}\left\{\left|\nu_n^{\prime}\left(A^*\right)-\nu\left(A^*\right)\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{2} \mid Z_1, \ldots, Z_n\right\} & \geq 1-\frac{\nu\left(A^*\right)\left(1-\nu\left(A^*\right)\right)}{n \epsilon^2 / 4} \\
& \geq 1-\frac{1}{n \epsilon^2} \geq \frac{1}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$
whenever $n \epsilon^2 \geq 2$. In summary,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{P}\left\{\sup _{A \in \mathcal{A}}\left|\nu_n(A)-\nu_n^{\prime}(A)\right|>\epsilon / 2\right\} & \geq \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{P}\left\{\left|\nu_n\left(A^*\right)-\nu\left(A^*\right)\right|>\epsilon\right\} \\
& \geq \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{P}\left\{\sup _{A \in \mathcal{A}}\left|\nu_n(A)-\nu(A)\right|>\epsilon\right\} .
\end{aligned}
$$

---

My specific questions are:

- Based on the penultimate inequality above, if there exists $A^* \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $\left|\nu_n\left(A^*\right)-\nu\left(A^*\right)\right|>\epsilon$, then $\mathbf{P}\left\{\sup _{A \in \mathcal{A}}\left|\nu_n(A)-\nu_n^{\prime}(A)\right|>\epsilon / 2\right\} = 1$, correct? Otherwise, why not?
- I don't understand why, in the last inequality above, $$\mathbf{P}\left\{\left|\nu_n\left(A^*\right)-\nu\left(A^*\right)\right|>\epsilon\right\} \geq \mathbf{P}\left\{\sup _{A \in \mathcal{A}}\left|\nu_n(A)-\nu(A)\right|>\epsilon\right\}.$$