# How is it possible to have a maximum of a quantity, but then no argument that attains this maximum?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, statistics, machine-learning

I am having difficulty with intuitive understanding of a definition in an exposition of the proof of the Vapnik Chervonenkis inequality in the notes of [Robert Nowak (2009)](https://nowak.ece.wisc.edu/SLT09/lecture19.pdf#page=2). The proof strategy is taken from the yellow book by [Devroye, Györfi and Lugosi (1996)](https://www.szit.bme.hu/%7Egyorfi/pbook.pdf#page=211).

**Context.**

> **Step 1**: First symmetrization by a ghost sample
> We are going to show that
> $$P \left( \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \Bigg \vert \hat{R}_n(f) - R(f) \Bigg \vert > \epsilon \right) \leq 2 P \left( \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \Bigg \vert \hat{R}_n(f) - \hat{R}_n'(f) \Bigg \vert > \frac{\epsilon}{2} \right). $$
> Notice that the absolute value term on the right hand side is now symmetric, involving two different empirical risks. Begin by defining $\tilde{f}(D_n) = \tilde{f}$ to be an element of $\mathcal{F}$ such that $\vert \hat{R}_n(\tilde{f}) - R(\tilde{f}) \vert > \epsilon$ if such element exists, otherwise $\tilde{f}$ is an arbitrary element of $\mathcal{F}$. You can think of $\tilde{f}$ as
> $$\tilde{f} \approx \arg \max_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \Bigg \vert \hat{R}_n(f) - R(f) \Bigg \vert,$$
> although this is generally not well defined there might not be an element in $\mathcal{F}$ attaining the maximum (because $\mathcal{F}$ is typically infinite). The formal definition is an attempt of circumventing this technicality that suffices for our purposes. Notice that $\tilde{f}$ is a function of $D_n$ (we dropped the explicit dependence to make the presentation cleaner).

On terms not defined in the extract:

- $\hat{R}_n(f) = \frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{i=1} \mathbb{I}(f(X_i) \neq Y_i)$ is the empirical risk under a training sample $D_n = (X_1, Y_1), \dots, (X_n, Y_n)$
- Similarly, $\hat{R}'_n(f)$ is the empirical risk under a ghost training sample $D_n' = (X'_1, Y'_1), \dots, (X'_n, Y'_n)$
- $R(f) = \mathbb{E}[l(f(X), Y)] = P(f(X) \neq Y)$ is the risk.
- $\mathcal{F}$ is a function class whose cardinality is not countable.

**Questions.**

I am comfortable with the idea that we are formally defining "$\tilde{f}$ as an element of $\mathcal{F}$ such that $\vert \hat{R}_n(\tilde{f}) - R(\tilde{f}) \vert > \epsilon$ if such element exists, otherwise $\tilde{f}$ is an element of $\mathcal{F}$."

*But what does the author mean when he supplies the intuition that we "can think of $\tilde{f}$ as*

$$\tilde{f} \approx \arg \max_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \Bigg \vert \hat{R}_n(f) - R(f) \Bigg \vert,$$

*and his explanation that there might not be an element in $\mathcal{F}$ attaining the maximum (because $\mathcal{F}$ is typically infinite)"?*

*In other words, how can we have a maximum of a quantity, but then have no argument that attains this maximum?*

---

In the original notes, the extract I supplied actually reads

> Begin by defining $\tilde{f}(D_n) = \tilde{f}$ to be an element of $\mathcal{F}$ such that $\vert \hat{R}_n(f) - R(f) \vert > \epsilon$ if such element exists...

but I think this is a typo and it should be what I have corrected it to in  my type up above with $\tilde{f}$.

This definition can be found in slightly different, but essentially the same language on page 211 of the linked book, and a similar unanswered question on this is also

[Theorem 12.4 in "A Probabilistic Theory of Pattern Recognition"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4604562/558645)

Comment: What's the largest element of $(0,1) = \{x\in {\Bbb R} \,:\, 0<x<1\}$?

Comment: In your example, there isn't one, the set has a least upper bound but no maximum as the set is uncountable. That I'm aware of, and while that insight is useful, it is difficult to see how that relates to this particular argument. Do you have any further thoughts?

Comment: I think the author just means that there may be no maximum, so we can't choose an element to attain it.

Comment: @Ted. Any idea then how this might be related to the definition of $\tilde{f} = \vert \hat{R}_n(\tilde{f}) - R(\tilde{f}) \vert > \epsilon$ if it exists, otherwise it is an arbitrary element in $\mathcal{F}$? It's not clear how the dots join up.

Comment: The author is clearly telling you that there might not be an $f\in \mathcal F$ achieving the maximum, but that you can get some insight by thinking about the situation where it is achieved at $\tilde{f}$. Their careful definition makes the proof work; the heuristic definition to help you get a grasp of the situation is the $\arg\max$ one.