# On a technicality in a proof of both the Glivenko-Cantelli theorem and Vapnik-Chervonenkis inequality.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, proof-explanation

**Question.**

I am having difficulty with both intuitive understanding and necessity of, a technicality in a proof of the Vapnik-Chervonenkis inequality in the notes of [Robert Nowak (2009)](https://nowak.ece.wisc.edu/SLT09/lecture19.pdf#page=2). The proof strategy is taken from the yellow book by [Luc Devroye, László Györfi and Gábor Lugosi (1996)](https://www.szit.bme.hu/%7Egyorfi/pbook.pdf#page=211).

1. *How and why is the construction $\tilde{f}$ necessary to make the two probability inequalities below work? Can someone parse my attempt to justify this construction and let me have some feedback on whether I've erred in my reasoning?*

2. *In Nowak's extract below, which of the following does he mean when supplies intuition on thinking of $\tilde{f} = \text{argmax}_{f \in \mathcal{F}}$?*

*a. The $\max_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \bar{R}(f)$ exists, but no element in $\mathcal{F}$ attains this maximum.*

*b. The $\max_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \bar{R}(f)$ does not exist, and so no element in $\mathcal{F}$ can attain this.*

A similar question on this technicality was asked but went unanswered:

[Theorem 12.4 in "A Probabilistic Theory of Pattern Recognition"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4604562/theorem-12-4-in-a-probabilistic-theory-of-pattern-recognition?noredirect=1&lq=1)

**Context.**

In [Nowak (2009)](https://nowak.ece.wisc.edu/SLT09/lecture19.pdf#page=2), the following comment is offered,

> **Step 1**: First symmetrization by a ghost sample
> We are going to show that
> $$P \left( \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \Bigg \vert \hat{R}_n(f) - R(f) \Bigg \vert > \epsilon \right) \leq 2 P \left( \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \Bigg \vert \hat{R}_n(f) - \hat{R}_n'(f) \Bigg \vert > \frac{\epsilon}{2} \right). $$
> Notice that the absolute value term on the right hand side is now symmetric, involving two different empirical risks. Begin by defining $\tilde{f}(D_n) = \tilde{f}$ to be an element of $\mathcal{F}$ such that $\vert \hat{R}_n(\tilde{f}) - R(\tilde{f}) \vert > \epsilon$ if such element exists, otherwise $\tilde{f}$ is an arbitrary element of $\mathcal{F}$. You can think of $\tilde{f}$ as
> $$\tilde{f} \approx \arg \max_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \Bigg \vert \hat{R}_n(f) - R(f) \Bigg \vert,$$
> although this is generally not well defined there might not be an element in $\mathcal{F}$ attaining the maximum (because $\mathcal{F}$ is typically infinite). The formal definition is an attempt of circumventing this technicality that suffices for our purposes. Notice that $\tilde{f}$ is a function of $D_n$ (we dropped the explicit dependence to make the presentation cleaner).

In Devroye, Györfi and Lugosi (1996), this construction is mentioned in the proof of the Glivenko-Cantelli theorem, and it is framed in terms of sets rather than functions, but they offer no further comment.

> To see this, let $A^* \in \mathcal{A}$ be a set for which $\vert \nu_n(A^*) - \nu(A^*) \vert > \epsilon$ if such a set exists, and let $A^*$ be a fixed set in $\mathcal{A}$ otherwise.

At a high-level, both authors use this construction $\tilde{f}$ to establish the following probability inequalities.

> $$P \left(  \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \left \vert  \hat{R}_n(f) - R(f) \right \vert >  \epsilon \right) \leq P \left(  \left \vert  \hat{R}_n(\tilde{f}) - R(\tilde{f}) \right \vert >  \epsilon \right) \leq 2P \left(  \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \left \vert  \hat{R}_n(f) - \hat{R}_n'(f) \right \vert >  \epsilon \right)$$

In particular, the construction $\tilde{f}$ appears to be used when the authors argue that

$$P \left(\sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \left \vert \hat{R}_n(f) - \hat{R}_n'(f) \right \vert > \frac{\epsilon}{2} \right) \geq P\left( \left \vert \hat{R}_n(\tilde{f}) - \hat{R}_n'(\tilde{f}) \right \vert > \frac{\epsilon}{2} \right). \tag{1}$$

But it seems to be crucial when the authors justify,

$$P \left(  \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \left \vert  \hat{R}_n(f) - R(f) \right \vert >  \epsilon \right) \leq P \left(  \left \vert  \hat{R}_n(\tilde{f}) - R(\tilde{f}) \right \vert >  \epsilon \right). \tag{2}$$

Definitions:

- $\hat{R}_n(f) = \frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{i=1} \mathbb{I}(f(X_i) \neq Y_i)$ is the empirical risk of training sample $D_n = (X_1, Y_1), \dots, (X_n, Y_n)$, where the $D_n$ are sampled from an unknown distribution $\mathcal{P}$.
- Similarly, $\hat{R}'_n(f)$ is the empirical risk under a ghost training sample $D_n' = (X'_1, Y'_1), \dots, (X'_n, Y'_n)$, also sampled from unknown $\mathcal{P}$.
- $R(f) = \mathbb{E}[l(f(X), Y)] = P(f(X) \neq Y)$ is the risk.
- $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \{0, 1\}$ is a classifier function.
- $\mathcal{F}$ is a function class, say all linear classifiers, or any other function class used in pattern recognition whose cardinality is countably infinite.

---

**My attempt to settle question 1.**

For inequality $(1)$, in order to see why the construction $\tilde{f}$ was necessary, I consider what happens when we forgo the construction, and instead try to apply it for some arbitrary $f$,

$$P \left(\sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \left \vert \hat{R}_n(f) - \hat{R}_n'(f) \right \vert > \frac{\epsilon}{2} \right) \geq P\left( \left \vert \hat{R}_n(f) - \hat{R}_n'(f) \right \vert > \frac{\epsilon}{2} \right) \tag{1}.$$

This amounts to showing the set inclusion $B \subseteq A$, where

$$A = \left\{ \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \left \vert \hat{R}_n(f) - \hat{R}_n'(f) \right \vert > \frac{\epsilon}{2} \right\}$$

$$B = \left\{\left \vert \hat{R}_n(f) - \hat{R}_n'(f) \right \vert > \frac{\epsilon}{2} \right\}.$$

Define some $\tilde{R}(f) = \vert \hat{R}_n(f) - \hat{R}_n'(f) \vert$ and fix $\omega \in \Omega$. Then if $\omega \in B$, then the real analysis result

$$\sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \tilde{R}(f) \geq \tilde{R}(f),$$

means that $\omega \in A$. In this case, I don't think the construction $\tilde{f}$ plays any role.

For inequality $(2)$, I follow the same strategy and consider what happens when we forgo the construction, and instead try to see whether the following holds for arbitrary $f$,

$$P \left(  \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \left \vert  \hat{R}_n(f) - R(f) \right \vert >  \epsilon \right) \leq P \left(  \left \vert  \hat{R}_n(f) - R(f) \right \vert >  \epsilon \right). \tag{2}$$

This amounts to showing the set inclusion $A \subseteq B$, where

$$A = \left\{ \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \left \vert \hat{R}_n(f) - R(f) \right \vert > \epsilon \right\}$$

$$B = \left\{\left \vert \hat{R}_n(f) - R(f) \right \vert > \epsilon \right\}.$$

Now defining $\bar{R}(f) = \vert \hat{R}_n(f) - R(f) \vert$, it would appear that the set inclusion does not hold, because by definition of the supremum as an upper bound,

$$\sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \bar{R}(f) \geq \bar{R}(f).$$

After fixing $\omega \in \Omega$,  if $\omega \in A$, we cannot conclude that $\omega \in B$. Rather, the above result seems to imply that $B \subseteq A$.

On whether a least upper bound exists, we know that $0 \leq \hat{R}_n \leq 1$ and $0 \leq R(f) \leq 1$, because the empirical risk $\hat{R}_n$ is an averaged sum of indicator functions, and because the risk $R(f)$ is a probability. And so $\bar{R}(f) \in [0, 1]$.

However, given a particular choice of function class $\mathcal{F}$ and a particular training set $\omega \in \Omega$, it may turn out in practice that $\bar{R}(f)$ is some sub-interval of $[0, 1]$.

To see why we cannot conclude $\omega \in B$ without the construction $\tilde{f}$, define the set,

$$\bar{R} = \{\bar{R}(f) \mid \forall f \in \mathcal{F} \}.$$

If we've fixed $\omega \in \Omega$, then $\epsilon > 0$ simultaneously partitions $\bar{R}$ into $\bar{R}_{\epsilon}$ and $\bar{R}_{-\epsilon}$, and $\mathcal{F}$ into $\mathcal{F}_{\epsilon}$ and $\mathcal{F}_{-\epsilon}$ where

$$\bar{R}_{\epsilon} = \{\bar{R}(f) > \epsilon \}, \quad \mathcal{F}_{\epsilon} = \{f \in \mathcal{F} \mid \bar{R}(f)  > \epsilon \}$$

$$\bar{R}_{-\epsilon} = \{\bar{R}(f) \leq \epsilon \}, \quad \mathcal{F}_{-\epsilon} = \{f \in \mathcal{F} \mid \bar{R}(f)  \leq \epsilon \}.$$

Case 1: $\bar{R}_{\epsilon} \neq  \emptyset, \bar{R}_{-\epsilon} \neq \emptyset$.

The following case appears to me to be the primary reason why we require $\tilde{f}$.

We now fix $\omega \in A$, and consider when the setting of $\epsilon$ results in a partitioning each of $\bar{R}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ into non-empty sets $\bar{R}_{\epsilon}, \mathcal{F}_{\epsilon} \neq \emptyset$ and $\bar{R}_{-\epsilon}, \mathcal{F}_{-\epsilon} \neq \emptyset$. Because $\mathcal{F}_{-\epsilon}$ is non-empty, an arbitrary $f \in \mathcal{F}$ might turn out to belong to $\mathcal{F}_{-\epsilon}$ rather than $\mathcal{F}_{\epsilon}$, and the implication $\omega \in B$ will not follow.

In this particular case, by defining,

$$\tilde{f} = \begin{cases} f \in \mathcal{F}_{\epsilon} &\text{if}\ \bar{R}_{\epsilon} \neq \emptyset \\ f \in \mathcal{F} &\text{if} \ \bar{R}_{\epsilon} = \emptyset \end{cases},$$

and noting that $\mathcal{F}_{\epsilon} \neq \emptyset$, then we can instead conclude that $\omega \in B'$, where

$$B' = \left\{\left \vert \hat{R}_n(\tilde{f}) - R(\tilde{f}) \right \vert > \epsilon \right\}.$$

This will occur when the function class $\mathcal{F}$ generates any of the intervals $\bar{R} = [r ,s], [r, s), (r, s], (r, s)$, where $0 \leq r < s$, and with $r < \epsilon < s$.

And also when the function class $\mathcal{F}$ generates a left-closed interval $\bar{R} = [r, s], [r, s)$, with $0 \leq \epsilon \leq r$.

Case 2: $\bar{R}_{\epsilon} = \emptyset, \bar{R}_{-\epsilon} = \emptyset$.

This seems redundant.

Case 3: $\bar{R}_{\epsilon} \neq \emptyset, \bar{R}_{-\epsilon} = \emptyset$.

A partitioning like this cannot occur for function classes $\mathcal{F}$ chosen such that they generate intervals $(0, s), [0, s], (0, s], [0, s)$, because $\epsilon > 0$ and so $\bar{R}_{- \epsilon}$ will always be non-empty in this instance.

However, a partitioning like this can occur when the chosen $\mathcal{F}$ generates a left-open $\bar{R} = (r, s), (r, s]$, and when $0 < \epsilon \leq r$, then $\bar{R}_{- \epsilon} = \emptyset$.

Because $\bar{R}_{- \epsilon} = \emptyset$, we will have that $\bar{R}(f) > \epsilon$ for any $f \in \mathcal{F}$, and so we can conclude $\omega \in B$, without the need for the construction $\tilde{f}$.

However, because we require $\tilde{f}$ to cover case 1, and because $\tilde{f}$ will select $f \in \mathcal{F}_{\epsilon}$ as long as $\bar{R}_{\epsilon}$ is non-empty, we can also conclude $\omega \in B'$.

Case 4:  $\bar{R}_{\epsilon} = \emptyset, \bar{R}_{-\epsilon} \neq \emptyset$.

A partitioning like this can only occur when the function class $\mathcal{F}$ is chosen such that it generates any of the intervals $\bar{R} = [r ,s], [r, s), (r, s], (r, s)$, where $s \leq \epsilon$.

However, if we fix $\omega \in A$, then we will have that

$$\sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \bar{R}(f) > \epsilon,$$

and so we need not consider this.

**My attempt to settle question 2.**

I can see the meaning of 2b., if we take $\bar{R}$ to be a closed interval $(r, s)$, then neither a maximum exists, nor any element in $\mathcal{F}$ can attain this maximum.

But I am struggling to see the meaning of 2a. If our choice of function class $\mathcal{F}$ generates some interval $\bar{R}$, say $(r, s]$, where $s$ is both the supremum and the maximum, then how can we have it that we cannot attain this maximum $s$?

Comment: @grand_chat. I tried to use the style of real-analysis argument applied to probabilistic settings you kindly showed me in an answer to one of my questions on the same proof a while ago. Would be glad to know your thoughts on the matter.